# Me.Close() not working in VB with WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm using VB with WPF and I am trying to close an application... the code I usually use ( Me.Close() ) is not working this time. The error it gave me was BC30545.. but it didn't help me understand the issue. Thanks for any solutions you all respond with.

Comment: There were absolutely no words in the error message? Just **BC30545** and nothing else at all? The information is on the screen in front of you, but we can't see your screen from where we are, so you need to include the details here in your question if you want our help.

Comment: Please show the code that is not working

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to prevent posting sub-par questions and getting downvotes and limited help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code **BC30545** corresponds with this message:

> Property access must assign to the property or use it's value

Make sure you don't have another method/property/control with the same name (For example, a button on your form called "Close"

In the case of this example, you'd rename to something like CloseBtn so that it doesn't interfere.